# Chroot multiple commans in docker container

Tags: docker, shell, command, chroot

i'm using a docker container to execute multiple commands within a chroot environment. My plan is to execute something like this:

```
chroot /host sh -c "command1 | command2; command3"
```

Obviously commands placeholders substituted with appropriate stuff.

The only way I managed to the this working was to use a script file:

script.sh:

```
command1 | command2
command3
```

and then setup the Cmd property of the container like so:

```
Cmd: [ "chroot", "/host", "./script.sh" ]
```

While this doesnt:

```
"Cmd": [ "chroot", "/host", "sh", "-c", "\"command1 | command2; command3\"" ]
```

And neither does this:

```
"Cmd": "chroot /host sh -c \"command1 | command2; command3\""
```

(tried single quotes too)

How can i get the command to work without the need to use a script file on filesystem?
Thank you in advance to anybody who can help.

Comment: A Docker container already is in effect a glorified chroot environment; why do you need to combine them?  (Are you bind-mounting the entire host filesystem into the container's `/host` directory and chrooting into that; in which case, why not run the commands directly on the host system, without changing the filesystem context multiple times?)

Comment: Yes i'm mounting the whole system. I'm doing this (instead of just executing in a simple shell) because I use the Azure IoT Edge system to distribute the container on multiple edge devices. This way I can run the command on multiple devices in a distributed way (for example if I need to update the azure daemon on 1000 devices I can do it using a container that runs the update command). I know it's a weird idea but it works---

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, the problem where the double quotes around the command. This works:

```
"Cmd": [ "chroot", "/host", "sh", "-c", "command1 | command2; command3" ]
```